# Cannot create VB6 ActiveX dll

Tags: com, vb6, activex

I am trying to create a simple VB6 ActiveX exe and call it from Excel.

In VB6 I create an ActiveX DLL project called BigTrev, using all the default settings.

I create a MultiUse class called Trev with a single method containing no code

```
Public Sub HelloWorld() 
End Sub
```

I make a DLL and register it from the command line (VB6 also registers it for me but I did it using cmd as well anyway).

Then it Excel I create a reference to my DLL in a new workbook. It clearly has been registered because the Intellisense knows about Trev and HelloWorld.

```
Sub cats()

    Dim derek As BigTrev.Trev
    Set derek = New BigTrev.Trev
    derek.HelloWorld

End Sub
```

It compiles in Excel, when I step through it it fails in the second line, the Set one. Error message is "ActiveX component can't create object".

Why? I have done this or similar loads of times many years ago when VB6 was used widely, I am using Windows 7 now and I am an admin on my box.

Comment: Fails how/with what error?

Comment: Sorry added to question, ActiveX component can't create object

Comment: Did you set the `Instancing` property of your class to `MultiUse`?

Comment: @Bond yes  it is MultiUse

Comment: 32 or 64-bit version of Excel?

Comment: @Bond Excel is 64-bit

Comment: Native 64-bit apps cannot load 32-bit binaries. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_ActiveXControlCOMAddinCompatibility).

Comment: Interesting, I created a VB6 exe and the same code worked so you could be right, although that article refers to ActiveX controls not DLLs. How can I use my DLL in Excel incdientally?

Comment: By ActiveX controls, they mean DLLs or OCXs that would get loaded into Excel's 64-bit process space. An "ActiveX Server" (EXE) should work fine as it runs in its own process space.

Comment: An ActiveX EXE and a DLL are both "ActiveX servers."  The former is an out-of-process server while the latter is an in-process server.

Comment: @Bob77 - Of course. I was trying to recall the VB6 template name used to create an out-of-process server. I was thinking it was called `"ActiveX Server (EXE)"` but I may be wrong.

Comment: It's just "ActiveX EXE" and pretty easy to spot.

Comment: @Bond: In VB4, they didn't have DLL's, only EXE's, and they were called "OLE Servers."  In VB5, the terminology changed to ActiveX EXE component and ActiveX DLL component.

Comment: @Bond: also, ActiveX controls are exclusively OCX's.  DLL's are just called ActiveX DLL's.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest registering the DLL (or EXE if that's the direction you've chosen) with the relevant regsvr32.exe. In this case, where you're registering a 32bit DLL for use in 64bit environment, use the one hiding out in c:\windows\syswow64.

Sadly, I don't have Excel (shock, horror) and the spreadsheet I do have (LibreOffice) is 32bit.